# How to reference a relative path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my controller, a function runs a shell command. I'm having a hard time to locate the script in the commad. For example, in my controller I have this:
def find_usage
    command = 'ruby usage.rb'
    `#{command}`
end

My question is where to put that usage.rb file and how to reference it without hard code the entire path. It works when I hard code the path as /home/user/xyz/usage.rb, but I don't think it's right to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could stuff it into /script and then reference `RAILS_ROOT/script/usage.rb` in your code.  `RAILS_ROOT` is a constant that contains the absolute path to your application.

Comment: hmm... but still I have to specify the absolute path, which I'm trying to avoid. The app will be deployed onto a different machine with different environment. So a hard code path doesn't seem nice.

Comment: Rails sets RAILS_ROOT for you when the app starts.

Comment: swingfuture - jdl is correct. You're using the variables RAILS_ROOT which is set automatically when the app is run, and then a relative path from your variable.

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated in Rails 3 in favor of Rails.root