# Issue showing images in RubyOnRails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on Rails 4 project that I need to store some images uploadaded directly by the users, and I must be capable of create a images gallery where a single user can only view their own uploads.

I'm uploading files with the CArrierWave gem, and it's doing fine. I'm changed the default uploads directory ( the public folder ) to a custom folder of mine ( /uploads/.....), but I think I'll not be able to show the images cause the 'uploads' folder can't be accessed directly, but I dont want to let the images on the public folder cause I don't want them to be freely accessed by anyone.

**Code of my view**

```
<div>

            <%= @photos.each do |p| %>
            <div>
                <%= image_tag (p.path_url) %>
            </div>

            <% end %>

        </div>
```

**My CarrierWave uploader class:**

```
class PhotoupUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "../app/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.album_id}"
  end
```

**and Photo model:**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :album

    attr_accessible :legend, :path

    mount_uploader :path, PhotoupUploader   

end
```

How can I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: It will be tough to help you if you don't show us some code. Also, where are you uploading the photos to (i.e. Amazon S3)?

Comment: Have you actually tried retrieving the images?  Assuming you did just override the `store_dir` method to specify your custom folder you simply be able to use the `retrieve_from_store` or `url` methods as normal.

Comment: @diasks2 This is more a conceptual question, not a code question..

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I'll try those methods

Comment: @GraemeMcLean I've been search about these methods and I can't figure out how to use them. Are they Rails methods or CarrierWave methods?

Comment: When using .url method on CarrierWave uploaded image I get a full path since my home folder: "home/user......./app/uploads/photo/path/1/03.jpg" ... is that the expected?

Comment: These are CarrierWave methods.  You should be able to do something like: `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>`

Comment: @GraemeMcLean it stills not rendering a single image. The image_tag is giving me the full path since my filesystem but the images arent rendering. I edit my post with my code...if it could help anything

Answer (score 0):

You would need to serve your images straight from the controller (see this question on how: [Rendering an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136161/rails-rendering-an-image)):

```
def image
  render :text => open(File.join('/uploads', user_id, params[:image_id], "rb").read
end
```

Usage:

```
<% image_tag "image?image_id=154" %>
```

Comment: That's different from my case, cause I have just locally stored files, and I don't want to make like a proxy,

Comment: By "being a proxy" you can control who can view which image. If you give _any_ static url, it will be available to all users, since it is static...

Comment: If I need to return a serie of images, the "image" method would be called a lot of times?

Comment: Once for each `<img>` tag you specify, yes. (just like with static files - one call per image)

Comment: When I using the "render" method, what is the folder on which Rails search for the file? Using the way you suggest, I ever got "no such file or directory" error message. Supposing I have a file located in: my_rails_app/app/uploads/photo/path/1/photo.jpg , how can I reference it on the render method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463854/how-to-reference-a-relative-path-in-rails